# neo4j query performance speedup

Tags: neo4j

Neo4J 3.0.3 / Windows Server 2012R2 / Java "1.8.0_91"

**Model 1**

```
Nodes
  Provider  {provSysId:21, specialty:"CHIROPRACTIC", state:"GA"}
  Member    {mbrSysId:1234, gender:"M", age:"60-64"}

Relationships
  (:Member)-[:VISITED {etg:89898989, servDt:15985, etgBaseCls:32123, mpc:"08"}]-(:Provider)
```

size: 258,109 nodes; 189,4871 relationships; 8,353,811 properties

Indices for `:Member(mbrSysId)`, `:Provider(provSysId)`, `:Provider(specialty)`, `:VISITED(etg)`, `:VISITED(servDt)`, `:VISITED(mpc)`

The query

```
MATCH (p1:Provider)<-[v1:VISITED]-(m:Member)-[v2:VISITED]->(p2:Provider)
WHERE v1.mpc='08' and v1.etg=v2.etg and p1.specialty<>p2.specialty and 
    p1.provSysId<p2.provSysId and abs(v1.servDt-v2.servDt)<=365
WITH p1, p2, count(distinct m) as cnt
WHERE cnt>5
RETURN p1.provSysId, p2.provSysId, cnt;
```

runs in ~80seconds

**Model 2**  (using suggestions from @stdob  posted in comments below)

```
Nodes
  Provider  {provSysId:33, specialty:"CHIROPRACTIC", state:"GA"}
  Etg    {epsdId:666666, mbrSysId:99999999, basCls:"Some base class", mpc:"Orthopedics"}

Relationships
    (:Provider)-[:TREATED {servDt:15985}]-(:Etg)
```

size: 512,102 nodes, 1,894,871 relationships, 3,890,381 properties

Indices for `:Provider(provSysId)`, `:Provider(specialty)`, `:Provider(state)`, `:Etg(epsdId)`, `:Etg(mbrSysId)`, `:Etg(basCls)`, `:Etg(mpc)`, `:TREATED(servDt)`

The same query modified for the new model

```
MATCH (e:Etg)
WHERE e.mpc STARTS WITH 'Cardio'
WITH e
MATCH (p1:Provider)-[t1:TREATED]->(e)<-[t2:TREATED]-(p2:Provider)
WHERE p1.specialty<>p2.specialty and p1.provSysId<p2.provSysId and 
    abs(t1.servDt-t2.servDt)<=365
WITH p1, p2, count(distinct e.mbrSysId) as cnt
WHERE cnt>5
RETURN p1.provSysId, p2.provSysId, cnt;
```

runs in ~40seconds.

Obviously is a lot better.  I am looking for any other suggestions for speedup.

Comment: What about index for `mpc`, `etg`, `specialty`? https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-schema-index

Comment: Thanks.  I just added the indices  `CREATE INDEX ON :TREATED(etg)`  (and the other two).  That makes no difference to the run time.

Comment: Try to clearly specify the direction of the `VISITED` relationship in a query. For example: `MATCH (p1:Provider)<-[v1:VISITED]-(m:Member)-[v2:VISITED]->(p2:Provider)`.

Comment: Adding the direction, the run time seems to have gone up just a wee bit.  I just profiled the query.  Would it help if I posted that output?

Comment: I think you need to change the model. Add node "Visit" and store in it the information about the visit: `(M:Member)-[:has_visit]->(V:Visit {etg:int,servDt:int,mpc,etgBaseCls:int})-[:to_provider]->(P:Provider)`. And add index to all `Visit` properties.

Comment: FWIW I just added the profile for the existing model.  Re: your suggestion to change the model, I think I will try an intermediate step before trying yours.  Will create a set of nodes called `ETG` who properties will include `mpc` and `etgBaseCls`.  Turn out that there is a hierarchical relationship between those three. I will still leave servDt as a relationship property.

Comment: @ironv Please be sure to edit your question if you don't have it solved, since you now have more information buried in the comments.